# Error:ManagedEnvResourceDisallowedByPolicy,Message:Fail to create managed environment because creation of required resources was disallowed by policy

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

While creating Azure Container app with Networking options via Azure ARM automation script I am getting the below error:

Error Details:

```
{    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/yyyy/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/xxxxx",
    "name": "testcontainerappsenv",
    "type": "Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "tags": {},
    "systemData": {
        "createdBy": "test@gmail.com",
        "createdByType": "User",
        "createdAt": "xxxx",
        "lastModifiedBy": "test@gmail.com",
        "lastModifiedByType": "User",
        "lastModifiedAt": "xxxx"
    },
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Failed",
        "vnetConfiguration": {
            "internal": false,            "infrastructureSubnetId": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/testvnt/subnets/aaaa",
            "dockerBridgeCidr": "10.1.0.1/16",
            "platformReservedCidr": "10.0.0.0/16",
            "platformReservedDnsIP": "10.0.0.2"
        },
        "deploymentErrors": "**ErrorCode: ManagedEnvironmentResourceDisallowedByPolicy, Message: Fail to create managed environment because creation of required resources was disallowed by policy, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2198255 for more detail.**",
        "defaultDomain": "xxxxxx.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io",
        "appLogsConfiguration": {
            "destination": "log-analytics",
            "logAnalyticsConfiguration": {
                "customerId": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here goes the policy which is blocking us in this case: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F783ea2a8-b8fd-46be-896a-9ae79643a0b1

Can anyone help us here by providing their guidance

After troubleshooting for few hours and going deep we found that the policy : https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F783ea2a8-b8fd-46be-896a-9ae79643a0b1 is not allowing us. In order to cross check we did a deployment without Networking and found it got created successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not a mandatory/default policy when creating container apps. If the policy "**Container apps should disable external network access**" is enabled at the tenant or organizational level, so it's not allowing.

Azure Built in [Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/policy-reference) for Azure Container Apps and know issues on this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy)

[image]

I reproduced the problem by enabling this policy on the tenant and attempting to create a container app.

[image]

Running below ARM templates should not be permitted because traffic from the Container App was made public.
[image]

*Basic templates from the portal*

**Template json file**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "environmentId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "containers": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "secrets": {
            "type": "secureObject",
            "defaultValue": {
                "arrayValue": []
            }
        },
        "registries": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "ingress": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2022-06-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.App/containerapps",
            "kind": "containerapps",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "properties": {
                "environmentId": "[parameters('environmentId')]",
                "configuration": {
                    "secrets": "[parameters('secrets').arrayValue]",
                    "registries": "[parameters('registries')]",
                    "activeRevisionsMode": "Single",
                    "ingress": "[parameters('ingress')]"
                },
                "template": {
                    "containers": "[parameters('containers')]",
                    "scale": {
                        "minReplicas": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**parameters json file**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "subscriptionId": {
            "value": "********************"
        },
        "name": {
            "value": "demoswarnaapp"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "westeurope"
        },
        "environmentId": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/****************resourceGroups/Compute-Resources/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/Testca"
        },
        "containers": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "simple-hello-world-container",
                    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest",
                    "command": [],
                    "resources": {
                        "cpu": 0.25,
                        "memory": ".5Gi"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "registries": {
            "value": []
        },
        "secrets": {
            "value": {
                "arrayValue": []
            }
        },
        "ingress": {
            "value": {
                "external": true,
                "targetPort": 80
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon disable that policy its allowed and deployed successfully.

[image]